# Are IPhone apps guaranteed to work on iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, ipod-touch

Since, I don't have the iPod touch simulator in xcode, and I don't have an iPod touch device there's not much of a way for me to test my app on this device. Since it works on iPhone 3gs and iPhone 4 can I safely assume it works on the iPod touch too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes, it should work just fine.

You need to think about things that aren't in the iPod touch. You won't be able to send a text from the device so you need to conditionally code for it. As long as you're smart about it, you can easily code for both devices without having to own both. I would suggest getting one though, even last year's model. It's worth the investment and reassurance.

Comment: Update for iOS 5 and later, you can send via iMessage from the iPod touch and the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can give that warranty. It all depends on how the app is implemented. There are certain differences between the iPhone type and the iPod Touch and as long as you code the app defensively (i.e. taking care that features that are not available can be overcome) you'll be ok.

The two most obvious ones are:

- not all iPod touches have all features present in the latest incarnation
- the iPhones are always connected
- the iPhone 4 has a second camera - for example, a mirror-like app won't work on anything else than iPhone 4 and latest iPod touch

The best thing you might want to do in your case is to run the app on an iPhone in Airplane Mode.

Also, might be worth looking around for a previous generation version - you can get good deals in the Apple Refurbished Store.